# javascript onchange running by itself

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with a javascript function.
It runs by itself when the page loads even if it`s set to run .onchange

I have a select that looks like this:

```
<select name="make_brand" id="make_brand" class="form_tag dispB width_full">
     <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
     <option value="1">Audi</option>
     <option value="2">BMW</option>
     <option value="3">Mercedes-Benz</option>
</select>
```

And my js looks like this:

```
// defining select fields
var brand = document.getElementById("make_brand");

// get values
function getSelectedValue(element, show_mark){
     return element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
}

// on select change
brand.onchange = getSelectedValue(brand, true);
```

When I refresh the page, the function runs automatically and I don`t know why. Can anyone help me with this?
I want the function to run on select change.

Comment: You're setting the event handler to the return value of `getSelectedValue`, rather than the function itself.  I feel like this ought to have a duplicate somewhere, but haven't found a good one yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is running your `getSelectedValue` function and then setting setting `brand.onchange` to it's return value. You can only set event handlers in that way if you do not need parameters.

You have two options for passing parameters to dom element events:

**You can make an anonymous function like so:**

```
brand.onchange = function(event){
    return getSelectedValue(event.target, true);
}
```

**Or you can add your event to your html element directly:**

```
<select name="make_brand" onchange="getSelectedValue(this,true)" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do...

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function init(){
var brand = document.getElementById("make_brand");
// on select change
brand.addEventListener("change", function(){getSelectedValue(brand, true)});

}

 // get values
function getSelectedValue(element, show_mark){
     return element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
}

</script>
</head>
<body onLoad = "init()">
<select name="make_brand" id="make_brand" class="form_tag dispB width_full">
 <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
 <option value="1">Audi</option>
 <option value="2">BMW</option>
 <option value="3">Mercedes-Benz</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

you have to let the document load before adding a listener to an element in the document. Notice the body tag, I called my init() function within onLoad.

Answer (score -2):

brand.onchange should be a function like this :
`brand.onchange = function(event){
    getSelectedValue(brand, true);
}`